# SQL Dictate number of joined rows based on column value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a strange requirement.

Say I have two tables:

```
ORDER_TB

  SEQ   PRODUCT_ID   ORDER_QTY  
   1        1            1
   2        1            1
   3        1            1


STOCK_TB
  LOCATION  STOCK_QTY
     A1        2
     B1        1


Desired Join Result:

PRODUCT_ID ORDER_QTY ASSIGNED_LOCATION
   1          1            A1
   1          1            A1
   1          1            B1
```

In other words, I'd like to assign each products in order table a location from stock_tb based on the quantity of stocks.

This doesn't look like a set operation to me. Is this possible with joins or are there any other clean alternatives in approaching this problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is get cumulative sums for each of the columns -- this gives you a first and last order for each value.  Then you can do a join on a range.

```
with o as (
      select o.*, cumesum
      from ORDER_TB o OUTER APPLY
           (select sum(o2.order_qty) as cumesum
            from ORDER_TB o2
            where o2.seq <= o.seq
           ) o2
     ),
     s as (
      select s.*, s2.cumeqty
      from STOCK_TB s outer apply
           (select sum(s2.order_qty) as cumeqty
            from STOCK_TB
            where s2.location <= s.location
           ) s2
     )
select o.*, s.location
from o join
     s
     on o.cumesum between s.cumeqty - s.order_qty + 1 and s.cumeqty;
```

Note: this works for the data you provided.  However, if the quantities in the two tables don't align, then the logic would be more complicated.

Comment: Oh my... I can probably make this work with what you've given but that's some heavy subquery going on there, and performance is a big criteria to us. Very roughly speaking, how would you compare the performance of your method to cursors? Or is that too dependent on the model of my data to make a meaningful judgement on?

Comment: Here is a good comparison of various methods to do running total (cumulative sum): http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals Bottom line - in SQL Server before 2012 cursor is the winner. In SQL Server 2012+ new analytic functions win. It depends, of course, on the size of your tables. With small tables any method is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use analytic functions:

```
with cum as
 (select s.*, sum(stock_qty) over(order by location) as cum_qty
    from stock_tb s)
select x.product_id, x.order_qty, y.location as assigned_location
  from (select o.*,
               row_number() over(partition by product_id order by seq) as curr_qty
          from order_tb o) x
 cross join cum y
 where y.cum_qty =
       (select min(z.cum_qty) from cum z where z.cum_qty >= x.curr_qty)
    or (not exists (select 1 from cum z where z.cum_qty > x.curr_qty) and
        y.cum_qty = x.curr_qty)
 order by seq
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e41b0/1/0